# WYSIWYG editor in texarea for Drupal configuration form

Tags: drupal, configuration, forms, textarea, wysiwyg

Is it possible to use a WYSIWYG editor in texarea
for Drupal site configuration form (system_settings_form).

This is how the configuration is coded now...

```
$form['my_module_text_bottom'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Some text'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('my_module_text_bottom', 'This is configurable text found in the module configuration.'),
    '#size' => 1024,
    '#maxlength' => 1024,
    '#description' => t("Some text."),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WYSIWYG or CKEditor modules should be able to do this.

Comment: I personally like CKEditor; you would download and install that module, then download the CKEditor library from the official site and place it in the correct folder. The instructions walk you through this.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is [for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1087468) and [Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/358316).

For D7:

```
<?php
  // Retrieve the default values for 'value' and 'format', if not readily
  // available through other means:
  $defaults = array(
    'value' => '',
    'format' => filter_default_format(),
  );
  $my_richtext_field = variable_get('my_richtext_field', $defaults);

  // Just construct a regular #type 'text_format' form element:
  $form['my_richtext_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => t('My richtext field'),
    '#default_value' => $my_richtext_field['value'],
    '#format' => $my_richtext_field['format'],
  );
?>
```

For D6:

```
<?php
  // Your saved or new data is supposed to have a value and a format. Just like
  // $node has a $node->body and $node->format. May also come from a
  // variable_get('mymodule_admin_setting', array('value' => '', 'format' => NULL));
  $mydata = mymodule_data_load();

  $form['myfield']['mytextarea'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('My textarea'),
    '#default_value' => $mydata->value,
  );
  $form['myfield']['format'] = filter_form($mydata->format);
?>
```

Comment: this is really a better answer since the WYSIWYG module won't do a thing without this code in place.

Answer (score 1):

I kept searching for this issue for about 6 hours and finally i found the reason, for your custom textarea field you must add this line, to use the default input format (Full HTML):

$form['format'] = filter_form();

be careful if you use this form element inside fieldset you must include this fieldset:

$form['donation-instructions']['format'] = filter_form();

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I found this question similar to:

[Drupal 6: Implement Wysiwyg on Custom Module Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353649/drupal-6-implement-wysiwyg-on-custom-module-form)

One of the answers there pointed to this drupal.org page:

http://drupal.org/node/358316

which provides fairly detailed examples of the "format" array key and filter_form(), also describing how it's used if your form has multiple textareas.

The approach given there doesn't apply to Drupal 7.

I ran into a similar situation where I'd downloaded and installed and installed CKEditor and it displayed when editing content nodes, but didn't display for the textarea on a configuration form for my module.