# Drupal 6: Implement Wysiwyg on Custom Module Form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, wysiwyg, drupal-modules

I have a custom form that I have written with the Form API. We have the WYSIWYG module and TinyMCE implemented on the site that this module will be used on. How do I implement the WYSIWYG api on my custom form text areas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help integrate WYSIWYG with your custom module forms: http://drupal.org/node/358316

Basically, you need to add the `format` key to each of your form fields and use [`filter_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_form/6)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody working with Drupal 7, here's the link to it that should help integrate WYSIWYG TinyMCE with your custom form fields: http://drupal.org/node/1087468

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working in drupal 7. Use the following.

```
$form['FIELD'] = array(
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => t('TITLE'),
  '#format' => 'full_html' //the format you used for editor.
);
```

In your form submit handler, you can access the value as follows.

```
$form_state['values']['FIELD']['value'];
```

Comment: How to get $form_state['values']['FIELD']['safe_value'] ?